# as_tibble only returns a single variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm very new to R and coding, and this is my first reach-out to SO

I have a data frame (brfss2013) with 491775 obs and 330 variables.  I want to take three of those variables ($qlmentl2, $misdeprd & $misnowork) and create a new data frame called "level_unhappy" with just those three variables

I've tried this code in R Studio, and the result is a data frame with 491775 obs (correct) and 1 variable.

````
```{r create_level_unhappy, results='hide'}
level_unhappy <-  as_tibble(brfss2013$qlmentl2, brfss2013$misdeprd, brfss2013$misnowork, validate = FALSE)

```
````

I've also tried this...

```
level_unhappy <- as.data.frame(brfss2013$qlmentl2, brfss2013$misdeprd, brfss2013$misnowork)
```

... and received...

```
Error in !optional : invalid argument type
In addition: Warning message:
In as.data.frame.integer(brfss2013$qlmentl2, brfss2013$misdeprd,  :
  'row.names' is not a character vector of length 491775 -- omitting it. Will be an error!
```

What am I missing?

Cheers,
 -eric

Comment: Without seeing your data, I can't really tell. But why not just `brfss2013[c("qlmentl2","misdeprd","misnowork")]` ?

Comment: Ah... I think I know the issue - you want `data.frame` not `as.data.frame` - compare `as.data.frame(1:10, 2:11, 3:12)` and `data.frame(1:10, 2:11, 3:12)`

Comment: Or more accurately, you can get the same error via - `as.data.frame(1:10, 2:11, letters[3:12])` where `optional=` is the third argument to `as.data.frame` but you are passing it something that can't be coerced to a logical input.

Answer (score 2):

The first arguments of `as.data.frame` must be a list of objects you wish to concatenate into a data frame, because the second argument is looking for the `row.names`. So to avoid confusing R into thinking that your second data frame are the `row.names`, and since you want to join *vectors*, put them all in a `cbind()`

```
level_unhappy <- as.data.frame(cbind(brfss2013$qlmentl2, brfss2013$misdeprd, brfss2013$misnowork))
```

You can also avoid this headache by using R's other base command `data.frame` instead of `as.data.frame`, which provides some circumstantial advantages depending on what you are trying to do. However, in this case your code would have worked as written with `data.frame`:

```
level_unhappy <- data.frame(brfss2013$qlmentl2, brfss2013$misdeprd, brfss2013$misnowork)
```

`data.frame` doesn't assume any argument is anything other than data to be combined unelss you explicate as much using an optional argument call like `row.names = "r1"` for example.

Comment: oh good point i didn't realize he was merging vectors, not dfs

Comment: Sorry to keep being a pest, but `cbind` makes a `matrix`, that then gets converted to a `data.frame`, which might destroy info - e.g.: `as.data.frame(cbind(factor(1:2,labels=c("a","b")), 1:2))` - you could chuck them in a `list` instead `as.data.frame(list(var1, var2))` but the `data.frame` method probably makes more sense.

Comment: Yes, that is addressed in my above answer w.r.t. the use of `data.frame`

Comment: @thelatemail this is the benefit of a reproducible example ;)

Answer (score 1):

`as_tibble` will do different things depending on what you pass as the first argument. By doing `as_tibble(brfss2013$qlmentl2, ...)`, you're passing a vector as a first argument. The `as_tibble` method for vectors is not set up to accept multiple vectors, and the other vectors you pass end up getting used as row names etc. Instead, I think you want:

```
as_tibble(bfrss2013[, c("qlmentl2","misdeprd","misnowork")])
```

That way, you're passing a data frame as the first argument. `as_tibble` will convert the dataframe to `tibble`.

This only really applies if you specifically want to convert your data to `tibble` though. Tibbles mostly work like dataframes, with a couple added features. If all you want to do is separate out those columns into a separate variable, you can do:

```
new_df <- bfrss2013[, c("qlmentl2","misdeprd","misnowork")]
```